# WordPress PDF Form Submission

Tags: wordpress, pdf

Good morning.  I'm learning WordPress on the fly for a community project.  The  project coordinator has some PDF files in Google Docs she would like people to fill out and submit electronically.   I have added links to the Google Doc files using   Elementor which works, but people would still have to download the file in Word Format and email them to her.  Could anyone point me in the right direction for Plugins or examples that would help streamline the submission of these predefined PDFs?

Existing Site:
http://chagrinfallsdi.com/join_destination_imagination/

Answer (score 0):

Exploring Formidable PRO2PDF as it looks like the best option to tackle this.